# Avoid decimals in laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I have text field input I use that as weight values and I want disallow using decimals like: `4.5` KG I just want to allow `4` or `5`, `100` nothing with `.3`

**Is there anyway to do such thing?**

## Code

`validation`

```
'weight' => 'required|numeric',
```

`form`

```
{{ Form::text('weight', 1, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "integer" on laravel validation like so:

```
'weight' => 'required|integer'
```

Comment: @mafortis This would allow negatives? Just confirming... Maybe set a `min` attribute as well.

Comment: @vivek_23, upvoted for that, heads-up for the `between` validation rule too, just in case mafortis haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @vivek_23 no man it doesn't allow negatives, it starts from 1 to whatever number but no negative. `PS` i don't think `min="1"` would work on text field i think that's just for number type inputs

Comment: @mafortis `weight` should be number type input anyway?

Comment: @vivek_23 matter of design i prefer to use text input, i just remembered i can put `min:1` in my validation :)

Comment: @mafortis Ok and yes, by `min` I meant `min` on Laravel side itself. Put it after `integer` check though.

Comment: @vivek_23 i thought you talking about my input field :-p anyway thanks for reminding me